# Is this sql query even acceptable?

Tags: php, mysql

another dumb question to brighten your day. I have this MySql query and, yes, it doesn't shown any result. What's wrong here? Is it the AND or the ORDERBY? hmmm...

```
 SELECT * FROM statisticData WHERE SYear LIKE '$SYr' AND accessDate BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate' ORDER BY accessDate DESC
```

Oh, this is what comes before the query:

```
   $SYr = $_POST['SYr'];
   $startDate = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($_POST['Date1']));
   $endDate   = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($_POST['Date2']));
```

[image: the needed inputs]

Comment: What are `$SYr`, `$startDate` and `$endDate`?

Comment: @Kolink, $SYr is what the user chooses from the dropdown list and the other two are what the users picks from the calendar. I'll include the screenshot.

Comment: The database despises you. Besides it does not no about those variables

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` say?

Comment: I used the same variables in two different tables and they're working just fine @EdHeal.

Comment: There is no mysql_error @AdamF. Just an empty table.

Answer (score 2):

Dates in MySQL *must* be in `Y-m-d` format. `m-d-Y` is not acceptable and will not return any rows.

[image: xkcd]

Also:

[image: xkcd]

Escape your inputs. Its okay for the date ones because you're handling them already and the output is a PHP-generated date. But `$SYr` is currently unsafe.

Comment: So, there is nothing wrong with the query? I changed it all and even added data in the table using now the right date formatting. The value of SYr may only by 1,2,3,4 or 5. I have an entry in the database with the value 4 for SYr and an accessDate of 2013-10-07. Whenever I choose these from the dropdowns, I still get noth'n. What could be wrong now? Thanks.

Comment: Try `var_dump`ing your input variables. Also, just because you only created `<option>`s for certain numbers, doesn't mean you are guaranteed to only get them ;)

Comment: @Kolink hello again, I tried var_dump for all the input variable and I got this as a result.-----> string(1) "4" string(10) "1970-01-01" string(10) "1970-01-01"

Comment: wait, that's the Unix epoch or someth'n right? So... it's with the conversion? My strtotime() is returning 0.

Comment: That's probably because it doesn't like the input format. What does `var_dump($_POST)` give you?